# Five inputs depends on the values of two selects

Tags: javascript

Good night.

I am trying to fill in several inputs depending on two different selects, where different combinations of both selects will give different results in the inputs.

At the moment I have this, but I don't know how to link 'race' with 'level' so that when both are selected the corresponding number appears filled, as who says it would be to put data from a double entry table in javascript.

```js
$('.raza').on('change', function() {
var value =this.value;
    if(value == 'Brujas y brujos');
   else if(value == 'Nivel nato');
    {
        $('.fue').val('6');
       $('.mag').val('10');
       $('.res').val('2');
         $('.vel').val('2');
         $('.vit').val('55');
    }
  if(value == 'Brujas y brujos');
   else if(value == 'Nivel nato');
    {
         $('.fue').val('8');
       $('.mag').val('20');
       $('.res').val('4');
         $('.vel').val('3');
         $('.vit').val('65');
    }
 
  if(value == 'Brujas y brujos');
   else if(value == 'Nivel medio');
    {
         $('.fue').val('10');
       $('.mag').val('30');
       $('.res').val('6');
         $('.vel').val('4');
         $('.vit').val('80');
      
          }
      
      if(value == 'Brujas y brujos');
   else if(value == 'Nivel total');
    {
         $('.fue').val('12');
       $('.mag').val('40');
       $('.res').val('8');
         $('.vel').val('5');
         $('.vit').val('90');
         
         if(value == 'Hijos de Eva');
   else if(value == 'Nivel nato');
    {
        $('.fue').val('7');
       $('.mag').val('0');
       $('.res').val('3');
         $('.vel').val('2');
         $('.vit').val('50');
    }
  if(value == 'Hijos de Eva');
   else if(value == 'Nivel nato');
    {
         $('.fue').val('9');
       $('.mag').val('0');
       $('.res').val('5');
         $('.vel').val('3');
         $('.vit').val('60');
    }
 
  if(value == 'Hijos de Eva');
   else if(value == 'Nivel medio');
    {
         $('.fue').val('11');
       $('.mag').val('0');
       $('.res').val('7');
         $('.vel').val('4');
         $('.vit').val('70');
      
          }
      
      if(value == 'Hijos de Eva');
   else if(value == 'Nivel total');
    {
         $('.fue').val('13');
       $('.mag').val('0');
       $('.res').val('9');
         $('.vel').val('5');
         $('.vit').val('85');
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"> 
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">
<select  name="titulos" class="raza"><option hidden value="" disabled selected>Raza</option><option label="Brujas y brujos">Brujas y brujos</option>
  <option label="Hijos de Eva">Hijos de Eva</option>
    <option label="Humanos">Humanos</option>
    <option label="Licántropos">Licántropos</option>
  <option label="Sirenas y tritones">Sirenas y tritones</option>
     <option label="Vampiros">Vampiros</option>
  </select>
  
  <select  name="titulos" class="nivel"><option hidden value="" disabled selected>Nivel</option><option label="Nivel nato">Nivel nato</option>
  <option label="Nivel primario">Nivel primario</option>
    <option label="Nivel medio">Nivel medio</option>
    <option label="Nivel total">Nivel total</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <table style=" display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; "><tbody><tr><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="fue" type="text" class="fue" value="" placeholder="0"> Fuerza</div></td><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="mag" type="text" class="mag" value="" placeholder="0"> Magia</div></td><td><div class="stats"><input id="res" type="text" class="res" value="" placeholder="0"> Resistencia</div></td><td><div class="stats" style="width: 120px;"><input id="vel" type="text" class="vel" value="" placeholder="0"> Velocidad</div></td><td><div class="stats" style=" width: 115px; "><input id="vit" type="text" class="vit" value="" placeholder="0"> Vitalidad</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

What could I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(value == 'Brujas y brujos');` <= having an if in this form does literally nothing.

Comment: `else if (...conditional...); {}` <= the `;` there is going to cause you issues because that is considered the single statement for the else.  The following `{}` will always happen

Comment: your layout is completely wrong, what interest in the question?

Comment: did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```js
$('.raza,.nivel').on('change', function() {
  var raza = $('.raza').val();
  var nivel = $('.nivel').val();
  
  if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('6');
    $('.mag').val('10');
    $('.res').val('2');
    $('.vel').val('2');
    $('.vit').val('55');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('8');
    $('.mag').val('20');
    $('.res').val('4');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('65');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('10');
    $('.mag').val('30');
    $('.res').val('6');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('80');
  } else if (raza == 'Brujas y brujos' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('12');
    $('.mag').val('40');
    $('.res').val('8');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('90');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('7');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('3');
    $('.vel').val('2');
    $('.vit').val('50');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel nato') {
    $('.fue').val('9');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('5');
    $('.vel').val('3');
    $('.vit').val('60');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel medio') {
    $('.fue').val('11');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('7');
    $('.vel').val('4');
    $('.vit').val('70');
  } else if (raza == 'Hijos de Eva' && nivel == 'Nivel total') {
    $('.fue').val('13');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('9');
    $('.vel').val('5');
    $('.vit').val('85');
  } else {
    // default?
    $('.fue').val('0');
    $('.mag').val('0');
    $('.res').val('0');
    $('.vel').val('0');
    $('.vit').val('0');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<select name="titulos" class="raza">
  <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Raza</option>
  <option value="Brujas y brujos">Brujas y brujos</option>
  <option value="Hijos de Eva">Hijos de Eva</option>
  <option value="Humanos">Humanos</option>
  <option value="Licántropos">Licántropos</option>
  <option value="Sirenas y tritones">Sirenas y tritones</option>
  <option value="Vampiros">Vampiros</option>
</select>

<select name="titulos" class="nivel">
  <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Nivel</option>
  <option value="Nivel nato">Nivel nato</option>
  <option value="Nivel primario">Nivel primario</option>
  <option value="Nivel medio">Nivel medio</option>
  <option value="Nivel total">Nivel total</option>
</select>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="fue" type="text" class="fue" value="" placeholder="0"> Fuerza</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stats" style=" width: 90px; "><input id="mag" type="text" class="mag" value="" placeholder="0"> Magia</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stats" style="width: 120px;"><input id="res" type="text" class="res" value="" placeholder="0"> Resistencia</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stats" style="width: 120px;"><input id="vel" type="text" class="vel" value="" placeholder="0"> Velocidad</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="stats" style="width: 115px; "><input id="vit" type="text" class="vit" value="" placeholder="0"> Vitalidad</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Note: I only do not understand why do you need **so many** libraries in such a small code.

Note 2: there are so many things here to optimize... Write a comment if you are OK with this answer and understand it, so we can try to optimize a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I could develop the rest from this. It's just that it's a STATS calculator from a role-playing game that I run, and I have a template of HTML generators that I've done before, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

using if / else if to do this is the best way to drive everyone crazy, especially when it comes to code maintenance.
you need to use a trancoding table for this:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   fue = document.getElementById('fue')
  ,   mag = document.getElementById('mag')
  ,   res = document.getElementById('res')
  ,   vel = document.getElementById('vel')
  ,   vit = document.getElementById('vit')
 
const raza_nivel =
      { r1_n1 : { fue:  6, mag: 10, res: 2, vel: 2, vit: 55 }  // Brujas y brujos
      , r1_n2 : { fue:  8, mag: 20, res: 4, vel: 3, vit: 65 }
      , r1_n3 : { fue: 10, mag: 30, res: 6, vel: 4, vit: 80 }
      , r1_n4 : { fue: 12, mag: 40, res: 8, vel: 5, vit: 80 }
      , r2_n1 : { fue: 12, mag: 40, res: 8, vel: 5, vit: 90 }  // Hijos de Eva
      , r2_n2 : { fue:  7, mag:  0, res: 3, vel: 2, vit: 50 }
      , r2_n3 : { fue:  9, mag:  0, res: 5, vel: 3, vit: 60 }
      , r2_n4 : { fue: 11, mag:  0, res: 7, vel: 4, vit: 70 }
      , r3_n1 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:01 }  // Humanos
      , r3_n2 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:02 }
      , r3_n3 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:03 }
      , r3_n4 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:04 }
      , r4_n1 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:05 }  // Licántropos
      , r4_n2 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:06 }
      , r4_n3 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:07 }
      , r4_n4 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:08 }
      , r5_n1 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:09 }  // Sirenas y tritones
      , r5_n2 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:10 }
      , r5_n3 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:11 }
      , r5_n4 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:12 }
      , r6_n1 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:13 }  // Vampiros
      , r6_n2 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:14 }
      , r6_n3 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:15 }
      , r6_n4 : { fue:0, mag:0, res:0, vel:0, vit:16 }
      }

myForm.oninput=()=>
  {
  let key = myForm.raza.value + '_' + myForm.nivel.value
  if (key.length === 5)
    {
    fue.value = raza_nivel[key].fue
    mag.value = raza_nivel[key].mag
    res.value = raza_nivel[key].res
    vel.value = raza_nivel[key].vel
    vit.value = raza_nivel[key].vit
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="xx" id="my-form">
  <select name="raza">
    <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Raza</option>
    <option value="r1" >Brujas y brujos    </option>
    <option value="r2" >Hijos de Eva       </option>
    <option value="r3" >Humanos            </option>
    <option value="r4" >Licántropos        </option>
    <option value="r5" >Sirenas y tritones </option>
    <option value="r6" >Vampiros           </option>
  </select>

  <select name="nivel">
    <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Nivel</option>
    <option value="n1" >Nivel nato     </option>
    <option value="n2" >Nivel primario </option>
    <option value="n3" >Nivel medio    </option>
    <option value="n4" >Nivel total    </option>
  </select>
</form>
  <br>
  <input id="fue" type="text" class="fue" value="" placeholder="0">
  Fuerza
  <br>
  <input id="mag" type="text" class="mag" value="" placeholder="0">
  Magia
  <br>
  <input id="res" type="text" class="res" value="" placeholder="0">
  Resistencia
  <br>
  <input id="vel" type="text" class="vel" value="" placeholder="0">
  Velocidad
  <br>
  <input id="vit" type="text" class="vit" value="" placeholder="0">
  Vitalidad
```